# Specifying targetVersion on NuGet package install

Tags: .net, nuget

All the projects in my solution are targeting .NET 4.6.1. When I add NUnit via NuGet, it then adds the entry to the packages.config with targetVersion=461. However, due to a dependency that depends on 4.0, I need to reinstall NUnit with a targetVersion=40. I've been looking through NuGet options but haven't found anything for this. Does anyone know if this is possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NuGet does not work that way. It looks at the framework your project is targeting and then installs the assembly that best matches that framework.

If you want to use the .NET 4.0 assembly for NUnit then you will need to either:

1. Change the reference manually after using NuGet.
2. Change your project to target .NET 4.0
3. Not use NuGet. Download the NUnit assemblies and directly reference the assembly you need.

Comment: I was hoping NuGet had some obscure feature that would save me the trouble. Thanks for confirming my suspicion.